# DocuSign REST API Using Postman SSL ERROR

Tags: postman, docusignapi

I'm trying to receive / send API calls from DocuSign using Postman Collection, and I am getting a SSL Error, leading to a no response call. When I tried REST API at home using Postman, I received zero errors, but with the same settings using my company's pc, I am receiving the error. Does anyone know exactly how to solve this issue?

[SSL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYI7b.png)

Comment: What does the console suggest when you open it?

Comment: The console just states "Error: self signed certificate in certification chain," and when I try to disable SSL Certification verification I am receiving an "invalid_grant" error

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with your corp Postman configuration or your work computer configuration.

Check that you're using a trusted SSL/TLS root store that is up to date.